# What is the correct way to minimize data held on the stack?

Tags: c++, memory

Preempt: (if anyone can link helpful articles explaining the stack and heap at a deep level, up to registers, would be much appreciated)
I am new to C++: I am trying to really grasp how memory management works. At this point, I understand any declaration of the type `ObjClass obj;` to have automatic duration within the scope it's declared in. Yet, `ObjClass* obj = new ObjClass();` stores the obj pointer on stack, but assigns it an address of memory on the heap. What I'm wondering about is, in more complex programs, what design pattern is used to prevent stack overflow? I could see the storage on stack quickly exceeding 1mb. Is this achieved by making multiple smaller functions which run, use stack, and then automatically deallocate?

Related Q: As for global variables, I know they are held in "static" storage, yet am unsure how that works in the context of stack/heap. How is their memory allocated, and is there a small limit like the stack? Is heap close to the size of system RAM minus the OS-reserved memory?

Comment: This is more of an engineering decision, that you can put objects of  "reasonable" size on the stack. Where what is reasonable depends on many things, like what kind of system you have. And on many systems the 1MB stack size is just a default that can be adjusted.

Comment: I've wondered this, the stack on my system is about 2MB I think, I'm curious what happens if you need more.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the reply. I am, but I'm a freshman so I'm a bit away from those classes, yet I'm still really interested in understanding this now because I'm not really satisfied with the surface-level explanations my teacher gives. But yes, I am excited for that class :)

Comment: @MichaelW: "*I could see the storage on stack quickly exceeding 1mb.*" You would be surprised how much 1 megabyte of memory is, and how much can fit into it. Judging how much stack space you need is something best left to *experience*.

Comment: The key here is that each function within your program gets it own stack space. So if you factor your code reasonably, unless you try and declare a 1,000,000 element integer array, you should have a hard time using up all 4M of stack space on a per-function basis. Otherwise, you are correct, you can allocate as much storage as you need (up to the limits of your memory) and your automatic storage is limited to an 8-byte pointer to access each block -- you can have a lot of them.

Comment: How is memory allocated? [Basic Tutorial - awkwardly written, but good basic introduction](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) **note:** it is written for 32-bit implementation, but you can, with care, implement the same approach for both 32-bit and 64-bit use.

Comment: Use **containers**.

Comment: @Zebrafish If you need more, most - if not all - OSs have a way to request a larger stack size. I believe there are proposals to add this into the C++ standard

Comment: In almost all cases, you don't run out of stack space. You can simply assume you don't, and fix the problem if you eventually do. If you use containers from the C++ standard library and avoid unbounded non-tail-recursive recursion, you'll almost certainly be fine.

Comment: Remember the memory on the stack is constantly being reclaimed whenever the function you are in ends. You should not be more than a few functions deep so stack space is rarely an issue. Elements on the stack are very fast to create and destroy so I would say use the stack as much as possible. Any large objects (like an image) **should** hold their internal data on the heap so you don't need to care about that. All you really need to care about is large chunks of data that *you* own. Put those on the heap. Use containers.

Comment: Automatic variables (Stack variables) are destroyed when the process exits the scope containing them. If you have a function that uses a reasonable amount of stack space, you can call it a million billion times and you still won't get a stack overflow. You normally only run into stack overflows when using recursion.